# How to group a flat list into categories and create a tab-separated value file using awk?

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script, sed, awk

Crosspost: https://www.nixcraft.com/t/converting-a-list-into-a-tab-separated-file-grouped-by-values/4517

I have a text file with a list of values. The goal is to create a tab separated values file, which I have managed. After which I would like to group them by its category. Here is a sample snip of my list

```
|01BFRUITS|
^banana
^apple
^orange
^pear
|01AELECTRONICS|
^television
^radio
^dishwasher
^computer
|01AANIMAL|
^bear
^cat
^dog
^elephant
|01ASHAPE|
^circle
^square
^diamond
^star
```

Values starting with a PIPE can be considered headers and values with a CARET are values to the header it is under.

So after much googling, man files, and searching through forums for help... I've managed to come up with two commands.. both output differently in my efforts.

First command:

```
cat test.txt | awk -v OFS='\t' '/^\|/{ c1=$0; gsub(/\|/,"",c1) } /^\^/{ c2=$0; sub(/^\^/,"",c2); print c1,OFS,c2 }' | sed -z s/\\r\\t\\t//g
```

Which produced:

```
01BFRUITS       banana
01BFRUITS       apple
01BFRUITS       orange
01BFRUITS       pear
01AELECTRONICS  television
01AELECTRONICS  radio
01AELECTRONICS  dishwasher
01AELECTRONICS  computer
01AANIMAL       bear
01AANIMAL       cat
01AANIMAL       dog
01AANIMAL       elephant
01ASHAPE        circle
01ASHAPE        square
01ASHAPE        diamond
01ASHAPE        star
```

The second command is:

```
cat test.txt | sed -z 's/\r\n\^/\t/g' | tr -d '|'
```

Which produced:

```
01BFRUITS       banana  apple   orange  pear
01AELECTRONICS  television      radio   dishwasher      computer
01AANIMAL       bear    cat     dog     elephant
01ASHAPE        circle  square  diamond star
```

Now my list has unique values in my test run. My new list has duplicates like so:

```
|01BFRUITS|
^banana
^apple
^orange
^pear
^banana
^apple
^orange
^pear
|01AELECTRONICS|
^television
^radio
^dishwasher
^computer
^television
^radio
^dishwasher
^computer
^television
^radio
^dishwasher
^computer
|01AANIMAL|
^bear
^cat
^dog
^elephant
^bear
^cat
^dog
^elephant
^bear
^cat
^dog
^elephant
^bear
^cat
^dog
^elephant
|01ASHAPE|
^circle
^square
^diamond
^star
^circle
^square
^diamond
^star
^circle
^square
^diamond
^star
^circle
^square
^diamond
^star
^circle
^square
^diamond
^star
```

And the desired output I am looking for is this:

```
01BFRUITS   banana  banana          
01BFRUITS   apple   apple           
01BFRUITS   orange  orange          
01BFRUITS   pear    pear            
01AELECTRONICS  television  television  television      
01AELECTRONICS  radio   radio   radio       
01AELECTRONICS  dishwasher  dishwasher  dishwasher      
01AELECTRONICS  computer    computer    computer        
01AANIMAL   bear    bear    bear    bear    
01AANIMAL   cat cat cat cat 
01AANIMAL   dog dog dog dog 
01AANIMAL   elephant    elephant    elephant    elephant    
01ASHAPE    circle  circle  circle  circle  circle
01ASHAPE    square  square  square  square  square
01ASHAPE    diamond diamond diamond diamond diamond
01ASHAPE    star    star    star    star    star
```

My intention is to group all values of the same value together and maintain the left header. I have no idea how to approach it with awk, sed, or tr. I did manage a way in excel, but the processing power it takes on my old computer is annoying. I think the cli will speed things up greatly.

So the question is can this be done with linux shell and if so, how?

Comment: Awk would seem like an obvious choice; you can learn the basics of the language in 15 minutes and probably learn enough to solve the problem yourself in an hour or two.

Comment: This is where I am now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove duplicate lines from a file formatted like this:

```
01BFRUITS       banana
01BFRUITS       apple
01BFRUITS       orange
01BFRUITS       pear
01AELECTRONICS  television
01AELECTRONICS  radio
01AELECTRONICS  dishwasher
01AELECTRONICS  computer
01AANIMAL       bear
01AANIMAL       cat
01AANIMAL       dog
01AANIMAL       elephant
01ASHAPE        circle
01ASHAPE        square
01ASHAPE        diamond
01ASHAPE        star
```

you can simply use `cat list.txt | sort | uniq`, or, if entries are sorted already, simply `cat list.txt | uniq`

Comment: Not trying to dedup the list. I'm trying to group it by values.  You can see the desired output doesn't match your answer. Thanks tho!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use ChatGPT to produce the following:

```
cat test.txt | sed -z 's/\r\n\^/,/g' | tr -d '|' | awk -F, "{ key = \$1; for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) { values[key][\$i] = values[key][\$i]\",\"\$i } } END { for (key in values) { for (value in values[key]) { printf \"%s%s\n\", key, values[key][value] } } }"
```

Desired results were spot on. Impressive!

I did change the file from tab separated to comma.

EDIT:

Here is the breakdown, provided by ChatGPT:

```
# Set the field separator to a comma (,) for each line
awk -F, '{
    # Store the first field in a variable called "key"
    key = $1
    # For each subsequent field (starting from the 2nd), append its value to an array
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        # Create an array called "values" that maps each key to an array of values
        # Concatenate the current value with any previously stored value(s) for this key, separated by a comma
        values[key][$i] = values[key][$i]","$i
    }
}
# After all lines are processed, iterate through the "values" array and output each key-value pair
END {
    # For each key in the "values" array
    for (key in values) {
        # For each value in the array associated with this key
        for (value in values[key]) {
            # Print the key and value (with any previously concatenated values)
            printf "%s%s\n", key, values[key][value]
        }
    }
}' input.txt
```

Comment: The problem is that because of chatgpt, there are no explanations on how or why this works.  SO it has limited usefulness to others.

Comment: @RohitGupta.. I made an edit for you.